# Getting error message from tenacity retry_state.outcome.result() results in program termination

Tags: python, tenacity

I'm using the python tenacity library to do exponential backoff of a funtion.

```
import tenacity

def log_attempt_number(retry_state):
    print(f"Retrying: {retry_state.attempt_number}...")
    print(retry_state.outcome)

@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(100), after=log_attempt_number)
def throw_exception():
    throw Exception("What is this exception?")
```

This code gives me:

```
Retrying: 1...
<Future at 0x7feeaf6354c0 state=finished raised Exception>
Retrying: 2...
<Future at 0x7feeaf401580 state=finished raised Exception>
Retrying: 3...
<Future at 0x7feeaf6354c0 state=finished raised Exception>
Retrying: 4...
<Future at 0x7feeaf401580 state=finished raised Exception>
Retrying: 5...
<Future at 0x7feeaf6354c0 state=finished raised Exception>
```

...

But I want to see the error message, not the Future object.
On their [website](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), all I can see as an option to get the error message is the function result() which gives me the error message and then terminates.

```
def log_attempt_number(retry_state):
    print(f"Retrying: {retry_state.attempt_number}...")
    print(retry_state.outcome.result()) #This function terminates the program

@retry(wait=wait_random_exponential(min=1, max=60), stop=stop_after_attempt(100), 
after=log_attempt_number)
def throw_exception():
    throw Exception("What is this exception?")
```

...

```
Retrying: 1...
What is this Exception?
worryword@WorryWord:~/Development/SOTests$
```

So my question is: how do I get the error message without terminating the program? I have an issue where the first error is not necessarily the 10th error, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I used a try-except like so:

```
try:
    retry_state.outcome.result()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This gives you the exception without terminating the program.